# How to update value of a textbox based on input of another textbox in a gridview using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which i have two textboxes. The senarios is such that the value I enter in one (txtCharges) should come as * 10 in the other textbox (txtTotalCharges). How to achieve this using javascript ? Markup code for gridview is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdFixedMontlhy" CssClass="gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Width="100%">
        <RowStyle CssClass="gridviewItemStyle" HorizontalAlign="center" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CheckBoxField Text="Select" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Bill_HeadName" HeaderText="Head" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Applicable_Charges_Category_Text" HeaderText="Type" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charges" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewColumnControls">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCharges" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Charges") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtCharges_FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server"
                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtCharges" ValidChars="0123456789.">
                    </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridviewColumnControls" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Days" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewColumnControls">
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Charges" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewColumnControls">
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalCharges" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtTotalCharges_FilteredTextBoxExtender" 
                            runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtTotalCharges" 
                            ValidChars="0123456789.">
                        </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                    </itemtemplate>
                    <itemstyle cssclass="gridviewColumnControls" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to do this specifically at the client side using javascript or it can be done at server side also?

Comment: yes.. multiple value (i.e. 10 here) will be entered by the user a client side, and simultaneously the end result should be displayed to the user.

Comment: @HotTester: why you want it by javascript. You can use @gvLearner method

Comment: If the user selects the input value then once the user selects the input you can update the Gridview with the new calculated value. Can you just elaborate more on your issue so that we can work on it. Getting the value at client side for the gridview control will be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fail ... lack of understanding above ... 
put the script on the page that suryakiran suggests (with a slight alteration) ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateTotalCharge(charge, total)
{
       $(total).val(parseInt($(charge).val())*10);
}
</script>

// in grid template
<asp:Textbox onkeyup='calculateTotalCharge(this, <%= totalchargestextbox.clientid %>)' ... />
```

as an attribute for the txtCharges box.
that way each rows dynamic id for the total box is passed in to the js on the client when it's called.

Answer (score 2):

You can add onKeyUp javascript event for the txtCharges as below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCharges" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Charges")%>' onkeyup="calculateTotalCharge(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now the Javascript as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateTotalCharge(elem)
{
       var totChargeid = $(elem).attr("id").replace('_txtCharges', '_txtTotalCharges');
       $('#' + totChargeid).val(parseInt($(elem).val())*10);
}
</script>
```

Also you must do the required checkups for NAN. Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: seems like the most straight forward response ... why are people questioning the guy for asking something so simple ?!?!?!

Answer (score -2):

You can do this on the server side also

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalCharges" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Charges"))*10 )></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you but i'm guessing it's because you failed to understand the question, the other person asked how to do this when the value changed on the client side not during a databind on the server, the request was for this but without a postback.